# My HTML button cannot activate JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I try to create a button with HTML and activate it with Javascript.
However, I found it fail to activate.
I've checked my path several times but it seems there's nothing wrong.
What should I do to make my buttons work? Thanks

**My HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Who is Happyguy?</title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content" id="txt1">
    <p>My name: Jung</p>
    <p>My birthday: 2000/12/25</p>
    <p>My phone: 09XXXXXXXX</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Do you wnat to be my friends?</p>

    <button id="btn1" oneclick="change()">YES or NO</button>
  </div>

  <button id="btn2" oneclick="hide()">藏起來</button>

  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>

</footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

**My Javascript**

```
function change() {
  document.getElementById("txt1").style.color = "red";
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("txt1").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: It's `onclick`, not `oneclick`.

Comment: @Reyno I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the event for click is wrong in your snippet. It is `onclick` and not `oneclick`.

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('txt1').style.color = 'red';
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById('txt1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="txt1">
  <p>My name: Jung</p>
  <p>My birthday: 2000/12/25</p>
  <p>My phone: 09XXXXXXXX</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Do you wnat to be my friends?</p>

  <button id="btn1" onclick="change()">YES or NO</button>
</div>

<button id="btn2" onclick="hide()">藏起來</button>
```